# OpenCV UIImageView setImage not working after creating UIImage from Mat

Tags: ios, opencv

I wanted to try out a simple example of OpenCV like this:

```
Mat greyMat;
cvtColor(image, greyMat, CV_BGR2GRAY);
filtered_image = [self UIImageFromCVMat:greyMat];
[color_filtered_view setImage:filtered_image];
```

where image is just another Mat (obtained from camera), executed if a button is pushed.

Unfortunately absolutely nothing happen. Image view stays blank.

setNeedsLayout and setNeedsDisplay do not help but if I rotate my device (and force the layout to adapt to the other orientation) the image is suddenly visible.

Whats wrong?

Update:

Found out that this problem occur only because CvVideoCamera is streaming to another view, hence not because of Mat to UIImage conversion. The question is rather why/how does this (a running CvVideoCamera) block setImage?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

today i had the same problem, i belive is something related to the fact that the setImage call is called from another thread. This code works for me:

```
dispatch_sync(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
   [color_filtered_view setImage:filtered_image];
});
```

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

The problem in your code is that by copying the src image you copy the whole image to the cropped image. There are two possibilities:

1 - Without copying data. Its the same as you did. But without the second step. In that case croppedImage is not a real copy it pointed to the data allocated in src.:

```
 cv::Mat croppedImage = src(myRoi);
```

2 - With copying the data.

```
 cv::Mat croppedImage;
 cv::Mat(src, myRoi).copyTo(croppedImage)
```

Use this [openCV](http://docs.opencv.org/trunk/doc/tutorials/ios/image_manipulation/image_manipulation.html) link for better understanding.
i hope it will work for you.

Comment: Thanks for your answer but its not quite the problem I have.